# What is the min number of edges in a strongly connected directed graph of N nodes?

Tags: graph-theory

Given a strongly connected component of a directed graph which contains N nodes: 
What is the min needed number of edges as a relation of number of nodes ? 
How to prove it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A directed cycle is strongly connected, so at most $n$ edges are needed – and this is sharp, since if you have fewer edges you either have a tree or can't connect all nodes.

Comment: This doesn't really prove that the upperbound is sharp.

Comment: I think it does prove it. 

If there are less than n-1 edges, we don't even have a connected graph. 

If there are n-1 edges, then we have a tree. It's impossible that a graph is a tree and strongly connected.

thus, there must be at least n edges (1)..
 since It's always possible to construct a directed cycle using only n edges and directed cycle is strongly connected.. then it's always possible to make a strongly connected using n edges.. (2)

(1) and (2) implies that min is n edges. @jMdA